# Proof that $\aleph_\lambda$ is a cardinal if $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

In the book "Sets, Logic and Categories" by Peter Cameron it is stated that,  if $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal then $\aleph _\lambda =\bigcup _{\beta< \lambda} \aleph _\beta$ is a cardinal.

**The proof from the book:**
"It is not obvious that $\aleph_\lambda$ is a cardinal. It is certainly an ordinal, since it is a union of ordinals.
Suppose that it were bijective with a section of itself.  This section could not contain all $\aleph_\beta$; but if some $\aleph_\beta$ does not lie in the section, then the restriction of the bijection takes $\aleph_\beta$ into a section of itself, a contradiction."

**My understanding:**
The author wants to show that there is no bijection between $\aleph_\lambda$ and any of its sections for it to be a cardinal. But I have trouble understanding the last sentence:
What does "the restriction of the bijection takes $\aleph_\beta$ into a section of itself" mean?

Comment: Here's the argument: If there's some (minimal) $\beta<\lambda$ such that $\aleph_\beta\not\in f(\aleph_\lambda)$, where $f$ is a bijection from $\aleph_\lambda$ to a section of it, then the restriction of $f$ to the set $\aleph_\beta$ would be a bijection onto a strict subset of $\aleph_\beta$. Repeating this process gives us an infinite descending chain of ordinals, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not immediately clear that the restriction of the bijection takes $\aleph_\beta$ into a section of itself rather than simply into a proper subset of itself, but the argument can be repaired. If there is an $\aleph_\gamma$ that is not a cardinal, there is a least such, and it clearly cannot be a successor cardinal, so it must be $\aleph_\gamma=\bigcup_{\beta<\lambda}\aleph_\beta$ for some limit ordinal $\lambda$.

Suppose that $S$ is a section of $\aleph_\gamma$, and $f:\aleph_\gamma\to S$ is a bijection. There is a $\beta<\lambda$ such that $\aleph_\beta\notin S$, so $S\subseteq\aleph_\beta$. But then $f\upharpoonright\aleph_{\beta+1}$ is an injection from $\aleph_{\beta+1}$ to $\aleph_\beta$, which is impossible.